# Textwatcher handlers don't call for number with EditText Phone input type in Android 9

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-edittext, textwatcher

I've encountered a problem with Android 9 and Phone input type EditText. If you set TextWatcher as a text changed listener, its handlers (onTextChanged, beforeTextChanged, afterTextChanged) won't be called.
Here's my code:

```
final EditText textArea = (EditText)context.findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("textArea", "id", packageName));
textArea.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
 textArea.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        Log.v("Unity", "string: " + s.toString());
                        if (!multiLinesMode) {
                            if (s.length() == 0) {
                                SendData(2, "");
                                return;
                            }
                            char lastchar = s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1);
                            if (lastchar == '\n')
                                close();
                            else
                                SendData(2, s.toString());
                        } else
                            SendData(2, s.toString());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        Log.v("Unity", "before");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        Log.v("Unity", "after");
                    }
                });
```

The handlers will be called for every button from a phone keyboard except numbers. 
If I use android 8 and below numbers are handled correctly.
If I don't set input type numbers are handled correctly.

Comment: android:inputType="number" try

Comment: It won't help, the result is the same.